# htaccess for dynamic web pages

Tags: php, .htaccess, dynamic-data

I have a website and i am using MySQL to store and fetch data from, there is a bunch of data of different destinations (Yes this is a travel agent website) i am wondering how can i setup .htaccess file to display SEO friendly URL

For example: http://www.mywebsite.com/flights-result.php?id=10 this URL is a details page for a flight to Entebbe in Africa, i would like to have the URL for this like http://www.mywebsite.com/Africa/Entebbe.htm

And so on for them, one more thing do i need to add this for every page? the data is being update on daily basis so is there any easy way to write URL automatically?

Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you give some more information as to the entry points of your app? How are requests dealt with? What's the framework/structure you're using?

Comment: What have you tried? You have the correct search terms (htaccess, SEO), try looking for them in SO or google.

Comment: @HappyTimeGopher i don't get your point, can you please be more specific?

Comment: @user1250285 Do all your app requests go into a central controller? Does each page type have it's own file? Are you using a PHP framework?

Comment: @HappyTimeGopher Yes website is using PHP, "flights.php" this page get the complete list for any flights (there is a column in MySQL called "name" it is being used to individualize the data for example for flights to Africa we type Cheap Flights to Africa in "name" column if visitor click on "More flights to Africa" it will take to "flights.php" page like this "http://www.website.com/flights.php?name=Cheap-Flights-to-Africa" and 'flights-result.php" this page displays the details for a particular flight example "http://www.website.com/flights-result.php?id=10" there is no separate file.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really think what you are trying to accomplish has anything to do with mysql. What you are looking for is called URL rewriting. There are countless number of articles out there that could show you the direction to follow. I am not very sure which web server you are using right not. I presume it is Apache. [Here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) is Apache `module_rewrite` guide.

Answer (score 2):

Given the original URL, there isn't all the information in there to use mod_rewrite to do this completely.

So what you could do it send all web requests to a controller file, and from there parse the request uri and load the correct page.

So in htaccess, something like...

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ controller.php [L]
```

Then in controller.php you parse the url and load the correct page.

---

A different option you may prefer, (if you're flexible on the specific final URL) is to have URLs ending up looking like this:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/flights/10/Africa/Entebbe.htm
```

This would likely be simpler to do instead of implementing a controller (although I prefer the controller for routing requests).

So in htaccess...

```
RewriteRule
    ^/flights/([0-9]{1,10})/([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)\.htm$
    flights-result.php?id=$1&country=$2&place=$3 [L]
```

Then near the start of the flights-results.php file you should load the data for the id, then check that the provided "country" and "place" are correct (to stop people just entering anything here), and return a 4040 if it's not.

Remember to change all the links your app outputs to the new style as well.

---

You could also, as you mentioned, hard code all these URLs into a htaccess, but that's not ideal :)

Comment: I really appreciate your helping hand but this question might make you beat me :$ i am not familiar with htaccess and PHP that much, i wonder you have written two codes for me to add in htaccess, can you please be kind and mention what to type in controller.php please

Comment: Exactly how the controller functions will depend on the rest of your app and existing codebase. You could make a really simple version by using PHP's parse_url() function, a switch() statement, then using "require" to load the correct files. You can search each of these mentioned functions here: http://php.net/ :)

Comment: Thank you HappyTimeGopher you were about to save me but i have less knowledge to follow your instruction, thanks for your time and tips.

Comment: This is the method I use, though I think that a friendly URL has no extension. I'd rather have a URL like `http://mywebsite.com/Africa/Entebbe`, where the MIME type says what kind of result it is, not the extension. I reserve file extensions for actual static files that have actual file extensions. Even a URL for a dynamically generated CSV file will not have a CSV extension in the URL.

Comment: @Marcus I agree things are cleaner like that.